# VPN to a Mac that is in sleep mode

Tags: vpn, macos, sleep

How can I log into and wake up a sleeping Mac remotely through a VPN connection?

Answer (score 0):

If the Mac is acting as your VPN server, you definitely *can't* connect to it while it's sleeping.

If you can esablish the VPN using some other means (your router, a VPN server, etc.) then you might try using Wake On Lan, but it's tricky to make it work on a LAN, and it gets *a lot* trickier when a WAN connection is involved.

Comment: I have System Preferences > Energy Saver > Wake for Ethernet network access checked on my iMac and I've never had any issues bring it out of sleep mode via a VPN session request. Either on my LAN or over a VPN session back to my LAN.

Comment: Never said it can't be done. But your VPN server needs to support it.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Remote Desktop can wake a sleeping Mac and let you log in, if you have that.